# Angular: Call function if textbox value has changed

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have multiple textboxes generated by `*ngFor`. I want to call a function on `blur` of a textbox, only if the current value has changed. Any simple idea to implement this?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="account" (blur)="getAccountAssociatedDetails(manualDetailsForm.get(['rows', i, 'account']).value, i)">
```

Comment: using `change` event instead of `blur` ?

Comment: But I want the function to be called only when the textbox loses focus.

Comment: And when is the `change` event fired ? `change`!=`input`

Comment: Cool... You just read my mind! Confused `input` with `change`. Thanks!